# VB.NET encryption and decryption

Tags: vb.net, string, encryption, ascii

so i have a system about encryption using modulo.

the encryption doesn't have problem, but the decryption of the string doesn't comeback to the original string.

here is my formula used for encryption

```
modByte(i) + modKey Mod 255
```

and for decryption, it will be
modByte(i) - modKey Mod 255

for example: i input the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. and put key as 254[image: here is what happens]

and this is what happened when i decrypt it back.
PS. i changed the formula on the encrypt button
[image]
this is my code for encrypt button

```
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
    If mod_TB_key.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pls Input Modulo Key Value", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        modKey = mod_TB_key.Text
    End If

    'modModulo = modKey Mod 255
    mod_TB_mod.Text = modModulo

    For i = 0 To modByte.GetUpperBound(0)
        counter += 1
        ReDim Preserve modConverted(counter - 1)
        modConverted(counter - 1) = (modByte(i) + modKey) Mod 255 'formula used
    Next
    mod_Tb_enc.Text = String.Join(" ", modConverted)
    For i = 0 To modConverted.GetUpperBound(0)
        counter += 1
        ReDim Preserve modchar(counter - 1)
        modchar(counter - 1) = ChrW(modConverted(i))
        mod_TB_encText.Text = mod_TB_encText.Text & (modchar(counter - 1))
    Next
```

the decryption also has the same code, but the only thing changed is the formula used "modByte(i) - modKey Mod 255" changing "+" to "-".

This is my code for "convert"

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0
    modValue = mod_TB_Input.Text
    For Each ch As Char In modValue
        counter += 1
        ReDim Preserve modByte(counter - 1)
        modByte(counter - 1) = Asc(ch)
    Next

    mod_TB_convert.Text = String.Join(" ", modByte)
```

Comment: side note: `Mod 255` seems to be not so correct, since the value you got will range only from `0-254`. That is, you lost `255`. Not sure if the range of data allow you tolerate this missing `255` in your case.

Comment: @Ian but the ascii chart on the website ranges from 0-255

but the characters start from 32 up to 255

Comment: You are aware that `255 Mod 255` resulting in `0`, aren't you?

Comment: @Ian yes, so i need to use 254? but what about the decrypt i was using, i'm still getting negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You have

1. An off by one error (from your Mod 255, I think (thank you Ian))
2. You aren't using ASCII in .net, but UTF8, AND as a consequence, negative numbers are valid values.

You need to 'fix' the code by either doing all your arithmetic in `byte` (which is the correct type to work with ASCII, OR you can clamp the values back to a `byte` after you are done converting it.

```
If modConverted(counter - 1) < 0 Then
   modConverted(counter - 1) = modConverted(counter - 1) + 255
End if
```

Comment: `Dim counter As Integer = 0
        modValue = mod_TB_Input.Text
        For Each ch As Char In modValue
            counter += 1
            ReDim Preserve modByte(counter - 1)
            modByte(counter - 1) = Asc(ch)
        Next

        mod_TB_convert.Text = String.Join(" ", modByte)`

before i do the encryption, i convert it first to ascii using these code.

Comment: @dadadadaryl You might be converting the input text into ASCII but you are converting your `Integer` into UTF8. You should NOT be using `Integer` with ASCII. Or rather, you should not be using `char -x Mod 256` with an Integer, since you will get a negative number, which then gets intepreted as a Unicode character as opposed to a ASCII character in UTF8.

Comment: can i still ask here later? i'll rewrite my code and i will try to use byte.